# Sort array with Objects inside of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
[
  ["name1", { count: 20 }],
  ["name2", { count: 10 }]
]
```

How would I go about sorting this array by the value of count?

I have tried using the sort function,

```
const sort = Array.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
```

But this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the second entry in the arrays inside the outer array. Your code is using `count` on the array entries, but they don't have a `count` property:

```
theArray.sort((a, b) => b[1].count - a[1].count);
```

Note also that you call `sort` on the actual array, not the `Array` constructor. It also sorts the array in-place, rather than returning a sorted array (it *also* returns the array you call it on, though).

Live Example:

```js
const theArray = [
  ["name1", { count: 20 }],
  ["name2", { count: 10 }],
  ["name3", { count: 15 }]
];
console.log("before:", theArray);
theArray.sort((a, b) => b[1].count - a[1].count);
console.log("after:", theArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use `console.log("after:", theArray)` in your example and scrap the `sort` variable. This would show the in-place behaviour of `sort()`. By capturing the return value inside a new variable, newcomers to JavaScript might think that it returns a sorted array and leaves the original array untouched.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - Yeah, that's a good point. I just minimally changed the OP's code, but I agree that it's better not to give the wrong impression.